# Rails where joins for different foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have workorders and employees tables.  Each workorder has an employee assigned and a supervisor assigned.

The workorder.rb has:

```
belongs_to :super, :class_name => "Employee", :foreign_key => "super_id"
belongs_to :employee
```

I'm trying to create a where clause with a joins.  It works fine for joining the `:client`. But, the `:super` doesn't work.

This is my current attempt:

```
workorders = workorders.joins(:client,:super).where("wonum like :search or description like :search or clients.client_name like :search or super.employee_full_name like :search ", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
```

I get back:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "workorders" INNER JOIN "clients" ON "clients"."id" = "workorders"."client_id" INNER JOIN "employees" ON "employees"."id" = "workorders"."super_id" WHERE (wonum like '%CHUCK%' or description like '%CHUCK%' or clients.client_name like '%CHUCK%' or super.employee_full_name like '%CHUCK%' ) AND (wostatus_id NOT IN (231,230,9263,9264,232))
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 236ms
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "super"
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `employees` table isn't being aliased as `super`, and doesn't need to be aliased at all in this case since it's only joined one time:

```
workorders = workorders.joins(:client,:super).
               where("wonum like :search or description like :search or clients.client_name like :search or employees.employee_full_name like :search ", 
               search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
```

And for the sake of your sanity (and anyone who reads this), please move this logic into a scope:

```
scope :search, lambda{ |term|
  %w(wonum description clients.client_name employees.employee_full_name).
    map{|field| "#{field} like :search" }.
    join(" or "), search: term
}

workorders = workorders.joins(:client, :super).search("%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
```